# how to destroy a chart apexcharts before changing the view

Tags: javascript, php, apexcharts

Im learning how to program in php and my projects has like 4 views that change after you click on a  so it chnages the content of the div, in one div theres a button that creates a graph(using apexcharts), but when i create it using .render and change to another view, it appears a lot of errors in console because i didnt .destroy that graph.

I dont even know how to solve this, the code of the proyect works all correctly but its not a good practice ignoring all those errors right? My code directly cleans the content of that div and after it gives some code but i dont know why it keeps the same.

this is the function that changes the content:

```
`function cargarContenido(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      let contentDiv = document.querySelector(".content");
      contentDiv.innerHTML = '';
      contentDiv.innerHTML = data;

      return Promise.resolve(); // Devuelve una Promise resuelta
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error al cargar el contenido:", error);
      return Promise.reject(error); // Devuelve una Promise rechazada
    });
}`
```

and this is the graph:

````
const formularioDatatable = document.getElementById("formGrafica");
      formularioDatatable.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        //Codigo de apexcharts para crear una grafica.
        var options = {
          chart: {
            type: "bar",
          },
          series: [
            {
              name: "Ventas",
              data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125],
            },
          ],
          xaxis: {
            categories: [
              "Ene",
              "Feb",
              "Mar",
              "Abr",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "Ago",
              "Sep",
            ],
          },
        };

        // Crear una instancia de ApexCharts y renderizar el gráfico
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

        chart.render();
      });`

```
````

Comment: So if you already have an existing chart - `destroy` it first? https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#destroy

Comment: I tied to do ir but it would give me an error before creating that graph, because in that moment it wouldnt exist. Nevertheless, i tried another type of graph from apexcharts and it doesnt give an error so problem solved :)